# How to ensure successful updating data before get them

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm new in react and trying to solve the problem related to proper communication between backend and frontend. 
First I want to update data in database and after that get updated data. Getting and updating separetly working properly. The problem is that Get request does not wait for updated data. How to ensure that get request will wait for response?

I tried to use async/await, promise, add something like yield call( success)/yield take(success) to below code, but it does not working as I expected (there is a chance that I didn't use it properly). Any suggestions?

```
function* update({ data }) {
  const { //some data } = data;
  try {
    yield call(
      //update
      },
    );
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(Error(error));
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a better example of what you've done to help better? You are on the right track by trying using promises so you wanna do something like `async function update(){ /// }` `async function get(){ /// }` then you can just wait for them to resolve in order like `await update(); await get()`

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to call API (get API) Note: Need t install Axios lib

```
demoVariable = () => {
    try {

        return axios.get('URL')

    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

After that, you have to use componentDidMount() method to handle the response

```
 this.demoVariable()
        .then(response => {
            if (response) {
                 // write here code fo if condition
                }
                this.setState({ //write here state })
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
```

And mention state as a null below of the class name 
like `state = { stateName: null }`

Using this you always get updated date from API

Comment: adding an axios dependency for network requests is unnecessary and this also does not really answer his question